# Why is Auth0 so widley used with Angular2 authentication

Tags: angular, angular2-routing, angular2-services, auth0

I'm trying to implement Authentication with my angular2 app and have seen majority of tutorials use Auth0 as token authentication, but this requires me creating a account with them and possibly paying. Is there any resources where I can find authentication without Auth0 or some 3rd party API.

I would think it should be straight forward where I have a service to login via the server and return a success message where I set a localStorage variable or cookie and this will determine if my guard on the route passes or not. I dont want to use a Auth0 login screen for my angular2 app.

Answer (score 2):

You don't need to use Auth0, you can implement your own authentication endpoint.

You need to generate token on server side and send them to client:
https://github.com/auth0/node-jsonwebtoken

You can use this package in your Angular 2 application to validate token:
https://github.com/auth0/angular2-jwt

On server side ( if you are using Express you can use )
https://github.com/auth0/express-jwt

Comment: To learn more about [JWT](https://jwt.io#introduction) please visit https://jwt.io#introduction , as a summary JWTs make authentication stateless and straightforward.